# What do 为至 and 即随之而至 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary

First phrase:

> 身死无名为至愚.

Second one:

> 他的犯罪记录即随之而至.

What would be a good way to translate those phrases?

Comment: iciba：（至（到） to; till; until）无名 nameless; unknown; indefinable; indescribable; reconditeness 
（１）iciba 翻译：Death is unknown to the fool （"notion of death unknown to fool")
（２）iciba：His record as a criminal pursued him wherever he went.无论他到那里,他的犯罪记录即随之而至.

Comment: regarding (1): http://iask.sina.com.cn/b/10461086.html,谥 left out?
身死无名，谥为至愚，耻及父母，为天下笑, 这是历史上传说司马相如一纸檄文平定西南的檄文中一句。

意思是说人死了也没有好名声，死后被人说成是天下最愚蠢的人，而且这种耻辱不但辱及自身，还要连累父母亲人，全家人都会成为天下人的笑柄。
谥 posthumous name or title; to confer a posthumous 
title, iciba翻译 result thus appears in doubt，＂died
without fame, titled a fool"

Answer (score 4):

The 1st `至` means `most`. `为至愚` means `be most foolish`.

The 2nd `至` means `arrive`. `他的犯罪记录即随之而至` means `then his criminal record followed (to arrive)`.

Comment: Yep. The 1st is in an ancient writing Chinese form. The 2nd is modern Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

为至 is not a word, but different parts of the sentence. 
The correct grouping should be

> 身死无名/为/至愚.  -- 《史记 司马相如》
>
> Dead without good reputation is the most stupid thing.

为： is，至愚：most stupid (thing),至 means “most” here.

**即随之而至**

即 means *then*, 随之而至 is ancient style expression for "跟随它（一起）到来／发生". If you are intetrested to ancient Chinese(文言文)，read this:

[usage of 之 in ancient Chinese](https://www.douban.com/note/211000327/)

[usage of 而 in ancient Chinese](http://www.chinabaike.com/article/122/1053/2008/200810261586466.html)

Comment: Yes, *without good reputation* maybe more proper one. Edited in answer.